# MySQL (SELECT FROM WHERE AND) not working

Tags: php, mysql

Hi im trying to get data of row ***WHERE value1 = '$value1' AND value2 = '$value2'***

Php file gets data of these values (on POST). but I don't receive any data.

When I send only value1 without value2 I get data but from all rows where value1 is.

Here is code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value1 = '$value1' AND value2 = '$value2'" ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);

 }

}
```

Comment: Did you try that in your favorite sql tool? Because `COUNT*` is not valid sql...

Comment: sorry, dont look at this...... its one of many  attemps to solve my prolem

Comment: So, what must I look at? The sql statement that fails has a pretty central role in the code, no? So, let me get this straight: with just a condition on column value1 you get results, when you add the condition on value2 you don't? Are you certain that there are records where `value1 = '$value1' AND value2 = '$value2'` are simultaneously satisfied? Have you tried printing out $sql and had a detailed look at the conditions?

Comment: I dont know why its not working, thats why ive came here for help.

Comment: Can you answer my questions and test what I suggest please? I'm trying to help with the very limited info you're giving...

Comment: $result->fetch_assoc() is already an array, so you don't have to put $row in a new array by adding the []. Try this  `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Post some test data, which should satisfy the query, but doesn't, and values for `$value1` and `$value2`. Without this, we are merely guessing.

Comment: Your code is almost certainly vulnerable to SQL injection.  Please don't build queries by concatenating strings, especially not when user input is involved. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `json_encode` at the end of the loop. You also shouldn't push onto the `$rows` array until after you've received a valid row; your code will push the `FALSE` value returned when you reach the end onto the array.

It should be like:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$json = json_encode($rows);
```